# Visual Studio 2010: breakpoints in dll-project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing a plugin for another app. After I press debug, dll is generated and put into the folder for plugins of that app, after that that app is launched. I can't use breakpoint's. they are not fired up. When I move mouse upon breakpoint, there's a hint 'this breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document'.

Where the problem is?

PS: And yes, i'm running in the Debug mode and not in Release. Yesterday breakpoints worked as they should. Then they start working only in main file. After I deleted .pdb file breakpoints stoped firing-up (despite .pdb file is created again after build).

PSS: I'm new to all this stuff

**UPD:** When I put a breakpoint into main source file. Breakpoints are fired. Compiled dll is loaded (in modules) tab.

Comment: How have you added the reference to the dll?

Comment: Have you looked in the modules tab in visual studio? Is your module loaded? Is the pdb file loaded?

Comment: @Oded,should I add reference somewhere to compiled dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple explanation is that your plugin simply never got loaded.  Debug + Break All and use Debug + Windows + Modules to check if your plugin is in the list.  If it is then you can right-click it and choose "Symbol load information".  It shows you where the debugger looked for the .pdb file.

Answer (score 1):

Is your app 'third-party'? I mean it's not a part of VS project, right?
In this case you should use Debug>Attach to process and choose main app process.